# Replace character in one column of CSV file with awk gsub

Tags: awk, gsub

I want to use awk to translate a CSV file into a new CSV file that has only a subset of the original columns. And I also want to replace spaces with underscores for one of the columns only. I've tried like this:

```
gawk -F "," '
{
  name=gsub(/ /,"_",$1);
  label=$2;
  print ","name","label","
}' ./in.csv >> ./out.csv
```

But gsub() returns the number of match occurences, not the replacement string. So I get something like this:

```
,1,label
```

instead of:

```
,name_nospace,label
```

How do I use awk gsub like this to replace a character for one column only?

Comment: How about some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't:

```
name=gsub()
```

as `gsub` returns the number of substitutions, not a string. Just

```
gsub()
```

and print the field you fiddled with, ie:

```
gsub(/ /,"_",$1);
label=$2;
print "," $1 "," label "," # or whatever you were doing
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify "name", change:

```
name=gsub(/ /,"_",$1)
```

to (gawk and newer mawk only):

```
name=gensub(/ /,"_","g",$1)
```

or (any awk):

```
name=$1
gsub(/ /,"_",name)
```

You should also be setting OFS instead of hard-coding commas, especially if you're modifying fields, so your script should be written as:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
  name=$1
  gsub(/ /,"_",name)
  label=$2
  print "", name, label, ""
}' ./in.csv
```

assuming there's some reason for using variables instead of modifying the fields directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk -F "," '
{
  gsub(/ /,"_",$1);
  # print only: ,NameValue,LabelValue,   as output
  # so 4 field with first and last empty as in OP
  print "," $1 "," $2 ","
}' ./in.csv >> ./out.csv
```

in this case a sed is also available

```
sed -e ':under' -e 's/^\([^[ ,]*\) /\1_/;t under' -e 's/^\([^,]*,[^,]*,\).*/,\1/' ./in.csv >> ./out.csv
```